# Handling undefined in a for ... of loop?

Tags: javascript

Suppose my code is as follows:

```
const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday'];

for (const day of days) {
  console.log(day);
}
```

It prints out 'Monday' and 'Tuesday'.

If for whatever reason, `days` is undefined, then I get a runtime error.

I could handle this by putting in code like the following:

```
if (undefined == days) {
  // logic here
}
```

To me, that seems a little clunky. Is there a way to have the `for ... of` loop ignore undefined values? Basically, treat it like a zero-length array and so the logic inside the for loop won't execute, but it won't throw an error either.

Comment: No.  If your array-reference variable may be `undefined`, you have to explicitly test it. You could also preceed the `for` with `days = days || [];`.

Comment: I’m on mobile at the moment, but would `for (const day of (days || []))` not work? It’s ugly though, and the variable should absolutely be tested before it’s relied upon. I get the feeling I was typing as you were editing.

Comment: Fwiw: Lodash treats undefined as an empty array. E.g ‘_.each(undefined,el=>...)’

Comment: ignoring it instead of testing it might create future headaches

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could always use a forEach, and a logical or `||` within a parenthesis block.

```
(days||[]).forEach(day=>{console.log(day)});
```

I suppose you could also use this in your for loop.

```
for(let day of (days||[])) {
   console.log(day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check for a empth value is to initialize a variable before using it, Either is a string, object or array. This way the programm understand the variable and can easily suggest function for you.

```
  //Initializing Varable
  let stringVariable = '' ;
  let objectVariable = {};
  let arrayVariable = [] ;
```

In your case

```
 let days = []
 for(let day of (days)) {
  console.log(day);
 }
```